# Cordova GeoLocation API not working in Android M Beta OS

Tags: android, cordova, beta

Cordova's Geolocation API is not working on Android device running with Android M beta OS. While other API's like network, device, camera, etc.. works fine in this beta OS. Only GeoLocation API doesn't work. Is this is an API issue? (location option was enabled under Settings>App_Name>Permissions. But my app is not shown under Settings>Location)

Note: Geolocation App works fine on the same app, installed over Android 5 & below OS versions.

Have even tried with new permission model mentioned in Android site. No luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Facing the same issue.Did you get any reason for this?I am getting "User denied geolocation" while getting current location , where as i haven't denied permission every for app

Comment: @Ritika, Still searching for answer. No luck yet. Same error message is thrown for me, even though geo-location is enabled for my app in device settings.

Comment: Tested on Android M Preview 2. Still issue exists

Comment: I'm having problem with geolocation en Andorid M...always timeout (I have a timeout of 10000, must be enough)...I tested the same app in an oldr andorid and works